# Recieving spam mail that is addressed to someone else

Tags: email, spam-prevention, bcc

I keep getting replied spam emails which are being sent to other users. I checked the header and bcc fields, I am nowhere in those.
This is the scenario:

```
FROM: spam@spam.net
TO: john@doe.net
```

Thing is, my email is not `john@doe.net`. It is `jake@doe.net`. As I said, I checked the bcc field and I cannot see myself in it. I tested this by sending myself an email with myself in the bcc field and then I can see the bcc field.

Anyone have an idea what is going on and how to stop this?

Comment: You better not show your email address here publicly!

Answer (score 0):

> Anyone have an idea what is going on ...

Internet mail uses the SMTP protocol which allows for the mail envelope to have different recipients than the contents. Your (unspecified) mail client might be showing you the headers in the contents, not the headers on the envelope.

> ... and how to stop this?

Use whatever rules your mail client provides to send this type of message to a Junk folder.

You can't stop the spammer from pressing his send button and you can't stop the Internet attempting to deliver it as instructed. However there are extra checks your local mail service (or remote mail-service provider) can implement - with possibly some cost.

Comment: Thank you very much! Your reply is really helpful.